# organizing json schema in liquid-xml projects

Tags: liquid-xml

I am an existing user of XML spy. xml spy supports project similar to liquid-xml. But the issue with liquid XML. I am not able to import an existing folder structure and files in project explorer.  Is there any way to achieve this.  We have very complex json schema and it makes references to subtypes in external files.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy your files/folders into the root of the project directory.

- Then on the project window press the "toggle hidden files" button (1)
- Your files/folders should now appear (2)
- right click on them and select "Include in projct" (3)

[image: Liquid XML Studio adding files to a project]